# Solve an integral with Stokes' theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

For $\gamma=\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2+z^2=9,x+y+z=0\}$ with positive orientation, find using Stokes' theorem:
$$
\int_\gamma ydx+zdy+xdz
$$

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stokes' theorem gives$\def\\#1{{\bf#1}}$
$$\int_\gamma \\F\cdot d\\r=\iint_S \nabla\times\\F\cdot\widehat{\\n}\,dS\ ,$$
where $S$ is a surface having $\gamma$ as its boundary.  In your case we take
$$\\F=(y,z,x)\quad\hbox{so}\quad \nabla\times\\F=(-1,-1,-1)\ .$$
As the surface $S$ is not given you can choose whatever is convenient, as long as it has $\gamma$ as its boundary.  Since $\gamma$ is a circle centre $O$ radius $3$ in the plane $x+y+z=0$, I suggest taking $S$ to be the disc centre $O$ radius $3$ in this plane.  Using polar coordinates we have
$$\\n=(1,1,1)\ ,\quad dS=r\,dr\,d\theta\ .$$
Can you take it from here?

It's not entirely clear what is meant by "positive orientation" in this case, so you may have to reverse the sign of the integral.

Comment: Thanks. do we choose $n=(1,1,1)$ or $n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(1,1,1)$?

Comment: For $\bf n$, doesn't matter, but in the integral it's $\widehat{\bf n}$ which has to be a unit vector.

Comment: How do you use polar coordinates on a circle in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: It's not a circle, it's a disc, and you do it in exactly the same way as integrating over a disc in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: OK, this is a solution my friend wrote, I'm not sure about the end: $\Omega=\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2+z^2\le9,x+y+z=0\}$,$\iint_\Omega (-1,-1,-1)\cdot(\frac{1}{\sqrt3},\frac{1}{\sqrt3},\frac{1}{\sqrt3})dS=\iint_\Omega -\sqrt3dS=-\sqrt3\iint_\Omega dS=-\sqrt3*\pi*3^2=-9\sqrt3\pi$

Comment: Yes, good short cut using area of the circle.